# How to create separate messages to separate users on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a sign up page (new) and a user profile page (show) created with the actions below. My question is how do I (as admin) create separate messages to separate users, i.e, users/1 a custom message, users/2 a custom message.

```
def new
    @user = User.new
  end



def show
    @user = current_user
  end



def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password,
                                   :password_confirmation)
    end
end
```

Comment: How exactly do you want to customize your messages?

Comment: By sending each user a custom written article on this user profile (show) page.

Comment: you can have a column that distinguishes users like type and then have the controller find the right article according to the type . Or you can have each user have a foreign key to articles. Many ways to do this

Comment: @elliot, do you want to customize `flash[:success]` message upon user creation or do you want to send already created users some custom articles from the DB or maybe write some custom article and then select to which user to send? It is not quite clear what exactly do you want to do...

Comment: I would like to send already created users some custom articles from the DB. Thanks

Comment: @elliot whats the table name of your custom message ?

Answer (score 0):

I assumed that your model name is custom_message which contain your custom messages. But you can change the right model name and get your solution.

## model user.rb

```
---
has_one :custom_message
---
```

## model custom_message.rb

```
---
belongs_to :user
---
```

then access to that message with

```
user.custom_message
```

Comment: That's great. Thanks a lot.